# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: android

I have been following a tutorial from [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) to make a Music Player app.
I have downloaded the code and built it successfully in Eclipse.
But whenever I try to run it, I get a runtime error:

```
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.musicplayer/com.androidhive.musicplayer.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at com.androidhive.musicplayer.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.playSong(AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.java:281)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at com.androidhive.musicplayer.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.onCreate(AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.java:80)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-07 12:03:56.144: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

My Activity is as follows:

```
package com.androidhive.musicplayer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private ImageButton btnPlay;
    private ImageButton btnForward;
    private ImageButton btnBackward;
    private ImageButton btnNext;
    private ImageButton btnPrevious;
    private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
    private ImageButton btnRepeat;
    private ImageButton btnShuffle;
    private SeekBar songProgressBar;
    private TextView songTitleLabel;
    private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
    private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
    // Media Player
    private  MediaPlayer mp;
    // Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
    private SongsManager songManager;
    private Utilities utils;
    private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
    private int currentSongIndex = 0; 
    private boolean isShuffle = false;
    private boolean isRepeat = false;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);

        // All player buttons
        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
        btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
        btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
        btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
        btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
        btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
        songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
        songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
        songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

        // Mediaplayer
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        songManager = new SongsManager();
        utils = new Utilities();

        // Listeners
        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

        // Getting all songs list
        songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

        // By default play first song
        playSong(0);

        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check for already playing
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                    }
                }else{
                    // Resume song
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Forward button click event
         * Forwards song specified seconds
         * */
        btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position                
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
                if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
                }else{
                    // forward to end position
                    mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Backward button click event
         * Backward song to specified seconds
         * */
        btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position                
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
                if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
                }else{
                    // backward to starting position
                    mp.seekTo(0);
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Next button click event
         * Plays next song by taking currentSongIndex + 1
         * */
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check if next song is there or not
                if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                }else{
                    // play first song
                    playSong(0);
                    currentSongIndex = 0;
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Back button click event
         * Plays previous song by currentSongIndex - 1
         * */
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(currentSongIndex > 0){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
                }else{
                    // play last song
                    playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                    currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
                }

            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Repeat button
         * Enables repeat flag to true
         * */
        btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(isRepeat){
                    isRepeat = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
                }else{
                    // make repeat to true
                    isRepeat = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isShuffle = false;
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
                }   
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Shuffle button
         * Enables shuffle flag to true
         * */
        btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(isShuffle){
                    isShuffle = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
                }else{
                    // make repeat to true
                    isShuffle= true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // make shuffle to false
                    isRepeat = false;
                    btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);
                    btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
                }   
            }
        });

        /**
         * Button Click event for Play list click event
         * Launches list activity which displays list of songs
         * */
        btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);         
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Receiving song index from playlist view
     * and play the song
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                     int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == 100){
             currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
             // play selected song
             playSong(currentSongIndex);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to play a song
     * @param songIndex - index of song
     * */
    public void  playSong(int songIndex){
        // Play song
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            // Displaying Song title
            String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
            songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

            // Changing Button Image to pause image
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

            // set Progress bar values
            songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            songProgressBar.setMax(100);

            // Updating progress bar
            updateProgressBar();            
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update timer on seekbar
     * */
    public void updateProgressBar() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);        
    }   

    /**
     * Background Runnable thread
     * */
    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
               long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

               // Displaying Total Duration time
               songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
               // Displaying time completed playing
               songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

               // Updating progress bar
               int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
               //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
               songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

               // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
               mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
           }
        };

    /**
     * 
     * */
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

    }

    /**
     * When user starts moving the progress handler
     * */
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }

    /**
     * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
     * */
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

        // forward or backward to certain seconds
        mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

        // update timer progress again
        updateProgressBar();
    }

    /**
     * On Song Playing completed
     * if repeat is ON play same song again
     * if shuffle is ON play random song
     * */
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

        // check for repeat is ON or OFF
        if(isRepeat){
            // repeat is on play same song again
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else if(isShuffle){
            // shuffle is on - play a random song
            Random rand = new Random();
            currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
            playSong(currentSongIndex);
        } else{
            // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
            if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }else{
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
     }

}
```

What is the possible reason for the error and how can I solve it?

Comment: put your all code over here

Comment: Miss, problem in your ArrayList, its size is 0, that's why IndexOutofBound exception is coming. Check on that line number, so you will get better idea.

Comment: ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException, you are trying to some thing from ArrayList which is not present

Comment: Debug and check where you get ArrayIndexOutOfBound.

Comment: So how can I solve it? any idea?

Comment: Please paste the code of SongManager class

Comment: You could remove the playSong(0) in onCreate, or add an if to make sure the size of the ArrayList is > 0.

Comment: @kedarnath Here it is:[link](http://pastebin.com/302zLNYH)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52157/array-index-out-of-bounds click here and join, let we solve noob

Comment: @MissNoob You dont have mp3 songs in your sd card..You need to check if the arrrayList is empty or not and then play

Comment: @kalyanpvs are you sure that by adding songs the error will go away?

Comment: @MissNoob yes..try to add some mp3 files to your sd card and try..

Comment: @MissNoob of course because if you dont have any songs in your sd card then that array list will be empty.

Comment: @MissNoob Wow.. Nice.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
    // Play song
    try {
        if(songsList.isEmpty())
         {
          Toast.makeText(this,"Songs list is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           return;
         }
        mp.reset();

        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        // Displaying Song title
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();            
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Error will occur if songlist size is 1 and calling playSong(2);

Comment: issue is at on create.. i dont think songs will start with 2, more over its the scenario where no songs present not looking for particular index based song.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
/**
     * Function to play a song
     * @param songIndex - index of song
     * */
    public void  playSong(int songIndex){
        // Play song

        if(songsList != null && songsList.size() > songIndex ){
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            // Displaying Song title
            String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
            songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

            // Changing Button Image to pause image
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

            // set Progress bar values
            songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            songProgressBar.setMax(100);

            // Updating progress bar
            updateProgressBar();            
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
          // do your handling stuff.
      }
    }
```